# Отображение List с Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

Какой из вариантов отображения листа с `Firestore` считается правильней?
Вариант 1:

```
class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final retrieveItems = context.bloc<CategoriesCubit>();
    retrieveItems .getData();
    return BlocBuilder<CategoriesCubit, CategoriesState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is CategoriesLoaded) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: state.categories.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: state.categories[index].listItems
                    .map((item) => Text(item.name))
                    .toList(),
              );
            });
      }
      return Container();
    });
  }
}
```

Вариант 2 вместо `ListView.builder`:

```
return Column(
            children: state.categories
                .map((cat) => Column(
                    children: cat.listItems
                        .map((item) => Text(item.name))
                        .toList()))
                .toList());
```

Или есть еще метод который более правильней?

```
Category.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    categoryName = data['categoryName'];
    listItems =
        (data['testItems'] as List).map((data) => Item.fromMap(data)).toList();
  }

 Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    categoryID = data['categoryID'];
    name = data['name'];
  }
```

Стрим:

```
Stream<List<Category>> getData() {
    return categoryData.snapshots().map((event) =>
        event.documents.map((e) => Category.fromJson(e.data)).toList());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения оптимизации вариант с `ListView.builder`, работает лучше. Так как он рендерит элементы в момент скролла (и лишь определенное количество штук). В то время как `Column` рендерит все элементы списка. Но также есть и обратная сторона, `ListView.builder` является более тяжелым для малого количество элементов (до 5-15 элементов, где половина из них можно показать на экране).

*По этому надо выбирать, отталкиваясь от задач...*